# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in mysql stored procedure with python

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

See this stored procedure

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_followers`(in _user_id int,in _topic_id int,in _type int)
MAIN:BEGIN

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS follow.user_id
            -- COUNT(follow.user_id) AS _topic_idcount
FROM
    follow
WHERE 
    follow.followee_user_id = _user_id
    AND (topic_id = _topic_id OR topic_id = 0)
GROUP BY follow.user_id;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS count;

END
```

When I am use test call to this stored procedure function in mysql workbench it is giving expected result as number of count.

But When I execute python code and dump the json out put of this query it is giving following result.

```
[{"user_id": 3}, {"user_id": 4}, {"user_id": 5}]
```

According to my view it is not considering `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS count;` this statement when I call SP form python code as fallow

```
results = execute_sp("get_followers", [user_id, topic_id, type])
```

here execut is my custom function.

```
def execute_sp( sp_name, paramaters ):
    #helper method to run sp's and return results
    db = Db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.callproc(sp_name,paramaters)
    results = cursor.fetchallDict()
    cursor.close()
    return results
```

pleas help me to solve this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to try this to see if it works - I can't test it at the moment...

results = cursor.fetchallDict() is returning the *first* result set, as far as mysqldb is concerned. I.e. the result from the first SELECT. Try adding a nextset() call, like this:

```
def execute_sp( sp_name, paramaters ):
    #helper method to run sp's and return results
    db = Db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.callproc(sp_name,paramaters)
    cursor.nextset() #Need the second result set in the proc
    results = cursor.fetchallDict()
    cursor.close()
    return results
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.